# Counting rows in a Google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a menu system with date and food columns.  The screen will have a [working date] cell that controls which rows show on the screen.

When the [working date] changes the script should run and :

- count the number of rows on the sheet with a date that matches the [working date]
- count the number of row with matching date and blank food cells
- add enough rows plugged with the date to fill the sheets screen
- add additional rows if needed to allow additional entry by scrolling the screen
- sort all the rows
- scroll the sheets screen so that the first row for the selected date is at the top
  This should all happen automatically when the user changes the [selected date.]

I am completely green on working in scripts and initially thought I could use the dcount function to get the counts.  I now believe that the sheet side functions can only be used from there.  I expect that in a script one will need to select a range of data and loop through it to get the counts. 
 I am pretty sure I could eventually figure this out but would really benefit if someone could give me a few pointers.

Thanks in advance - Joe

Answer (score 0):

For the whole process you would need to use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to execute a function each time the sheets is edited and use it's [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) information to conditionally run the code when the [working date] cell is the one edited. I would use the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) version of the trigger which has less restrictions.

For all the actions you want to achieve you'd have to use the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#methods) methods.

1 and 2) Create a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext) object from a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object and set it up to make the search. When you set up the range for the text finder, avoid using [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) version of the getRange method or it may throw an error.

3 and 4) With [insertRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex) method you can insert rows to the [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object, and then use its `getRange` and `setRange` methods to set the values. There's no trigger available you could use to run a function when the user scrolls the view.

5) You can use the [sort](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj) method. Or get the range values, sort them with JavaScript methods and then set the ordered array in the range.

6) You can use the [activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate) method of a Range object which will put the focus in the range cell(s).